# How to print the series in python

Tags: python, series

This  is a given series I want to print it programmatically *0,-1,1,-2,0,1,0,2,-1,1,2,1,3,0,2*

Here the series is generated in such a way that it starts from *0* and next numbers are *0-1=-1* and *0+1 =1*  which makes series *0,-1,1* and next numbers in series are resultant of same operation *num-1*, *num+1* but on the first element generated by zeroth element example *0-1=-1-1=-2*, *0-1=-1+1=0* which makes the series *0,-1,1,-2,0* and so on.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add what you have tried so far, what problem you are facing and provide a minimal reproducible example. It would help answering the question.

Comment: _"... and so on"_: That's not clear at all. How is the next number in the series `1`?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which series are these but if you can provide series name maybe we can help better!

If you want to create number of series and put them in list in python you can try below.As far as I understand you want your series to start from 0 and next elements are gonna be (0-1) and (0+1).

```
series = []

for i in range(0,3):
    series.append(i)
    series.append(i-1)
    series.append(i +1)

print(series)
```

Result is;

```
[0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3]
```

My result is probably is not your desired output but if you can clarify math behind your series can help more.

Comment: check my solution for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```
a=0
for i in range(5):
    a1 = a
    print(a,end=',')
    while True:
        b=a-1
        print(b,end=',')
        c=a+1
        print(c,end=',')
        a=b
        if c==a1:
            break
    a1 = a1+1
    a = a1
```

solution

```
0,-1,1,-2,0,1,0,2,-1,1,2,1,3,0,2,3,2,4,1,3,4,3,5,2,4,
```

Comment: Now its much clear :). Guess you've found solution. Still need help?